# How to deal with dual servers and temporary files

Tags: file-handling, file-storage

Our application is hosted on a dual-server environment - when one server is overloaded with work, a secondary server will take its place in processing certain actions.  For most purposes, this isn't a huge problem.

However, our application generates documents and writes them to a database - and to do this, currently uses a temporary storage folder on the server side to write the document, send it to the server, and then display it to the user.  When the server decides it needs to shift processing over to the secondary server, this can cause a failure to write the document to the database.

How can we avoid this dual-server issue, without changing the structure of the server itself?  What can we change in the application that could allow us to retrieve the appropriate document every time?

I am not aware of any way for us to direclty reference which of the two servers to access, so that is not an option for us.

Answer (score 2):

Either put the document in a central location (database or shared file system), using unique file names or identifiers for each document created, or recreate the document on each server, whenever it is found to be missing.

Comment: That is what I was thinking - but we don't actually have control over which server is being used by our application, and as far as I'm aware, we don't have a shared file system either.  But I can ask if such a system might exist.  As for creating the document on each server, I don't think there's a way to choose which server is being referenced either, though I can also ask this of our server group.